# How do I make a relative layout an item of my ListView? And detect gestures over my ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, gesture

I am trying to make a ListView that has relative layout items, one after another. Each relative layout consists of a Button view, followed by three TextViews aligned to the right of the Button, and below each other. My RelativeLayout XML code is as follows, and it is fine, but how do I make it so that I can populate my ListView with this template after a button press, and how can I manipulate the text inside the textviews so that they say different things for each relative layout item?

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonA"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="100sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="SomeText"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:onClick="butt"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name:"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonA"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date:"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonA"
                android:layout_below="@+id/name"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Duration:"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonA"
                android:layout_below="@+id/date"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for the help

Edit: Someone has asked me to share how I am trying to implement this. Honestly, thats the part I'm entirely confused about. I'm new to java and programming in general. I've looked over the documentation here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

here is where I am trying to add an item into the listview

```
public void startStop(View view){
    Button ssButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ssbutton);
    if(startStopTracker == 0){
        ssButton.setText("STOP");
        ssButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F44336"));
        startStopTracker = 1;
        enableSwipe = false;
        return;
    }
    if(startStopTracker == 1){
        ssButton.setText("START");
        ssButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0D47A1"));
        startStopTracker = 0;
        enableSwipe = true;

        convoLV.addView(convoButtons[0]);


        return;
    }
}
```

where convoLV is the listview and convoButtons is supposed to be an array of relative layouts.

EDIT 2:
I implemented a version of Nolly's code with a change in the getListItemData() method so that only one item is adde  to the list each time. I also initialized the List listViewItems globally in the activity so that each item would add on. It seems so far to be what I am looking for. However; I am running into an issue where my activity can't detect gestures over the area of my ListView. This is an issue because I use the GestureDetector.onGestureListener.onFling() method to switch between displaying layouts. How can I detect gestures over my ListView?

Comment: What is the code you are trying? Please share your code?

Comment: honestly, thats the part I'm entirely confused about. I'm new to java and programming in general. I've looked over the documentation here 

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

here is where I am trying to add an item into the listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a layout you want to add to a ListView,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonA"
    android:layout_width="100sp"
    android:layout_height="100sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:onClick="butt"
    android:text="SomeText"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonA"
    android:text="Name:"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonA"
    android:text="Date:"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/duration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/date"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonA"
    android:text="Duration:"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

then you have to create an Adapter that will inflates your layout file. It will bind your data to the item views in your layout.

The Adapter code is below

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater lInflater;
private List<ItemObjects> listStorage;

public ListAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObjects> customizedListView) {
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    listStorage = customizedListView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listStorage.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listStorage.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder listViewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        listViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);

        listViewHolder.image = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonA);

        listViewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        listViewHolder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        listViewHolder.duration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.duration);

        convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
    } else {
        listViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    listViewHolder.name.setText(listStorage.get(position).getName());
    listViewHolder.date.setText(listStorage.get(position).getDate());
    listViewHolder.duration.setText(listStorage.get(position).getDuration());

    listViewHolder.image.setText(listStorage.get(position).getImage());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    Button image;
    TextView name;
    TextView date;
    TextView duration;

}
}
```

Create an object class that will hold data for the items in your layout file. See the code below. You can modify it to suit your needs

```
public class ItemObjects {

private String image;

private String name;
private String date;
private String duration;

public ItemObjects(String image, String name, String date, String duration) {
    this.image = image;
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
    this.duration = duration;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public String getDuration() {
    return duration;
}
}
```

Now we will create an Activity file with its layout file. In the activity layout file, add a ListView widget in the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mechanics"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:dividerHeight="1.0sp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, in your activity class, the ListView is instantiated. An object of the Adapter class is also create. The data object is passed as one of the parameters in the Adapter class

Finally, call the setAdapter() method of the ListView and pass the object of the adapter class as parameter to it.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestingListView extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_testing_list_view);

    ListView mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mechanics);
    ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, getListItemData());
    mListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

private List getListItemData() {
    List<ItemObjects> listViewItems = new ArrayList<ItemObjects>();
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Good", "Peter", "12-03-1989", "400"));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Good", "John", "10-04-1999", "560"));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Good", "James", "01-09-1970", "320"));
    return listViewItems;
}
}
```

This code was not tested. I hope it gives you an idea of what you are planning to achieve.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will experiment with this and let you know how it works

Comment: Hi Nolly, I implemented a version of the code you suggested with a change in the getListItemData() method so that only one item is adde  to the list each time. I also initialized the List listViewItems globally in the activity so that each item would add on. It seems so far to be what I am looking for. However; I am running into an issue where my activity can't detect gestures over the area of my ListView. This is an issue because I use the GestureDetector.onGestureListener.onFling() method to switch between displaying layouts. Do you have any suggestions for this?